# Sqlite3 naming db file with a variable in python

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite

How can I use the current date to name my db file so when it runs it creates a db file which is named after the current date. This is what I have so far:

```
import sqlite3
import time


timedbname = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

# Connecting to the database file
conn = sqlite3.connect(???)
```

with this error its the same with '/' or '-' or '.' in "%d/%m/%Y":

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(timedbname, '.db')
TypeError: a float is required
27.01.2016
```

Comment: Did you try using a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
import sqlite3
import time


timedbname = time.strftime("_" + "%d.%m.%Y")
conn = sqlite3.connect(timedbname + '.db')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

`time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")`

I guess it doesn't work because of the slashes in the generated date.

Comment: What do I put in:  conn = sqlite3.connect(here?)

Comment: I never used sqlite3, but I you probably need to use
`conn = sqlite3.connect(timedbname)` there.

I have looked up a bit of sqlite3 and it seems it should create the database if it doesn't exist yet, so you should be fine with this.

Comment: I solved it, you can look at my answer. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can't have dashes in your table name. Also it can't start with a digit.

```
import sqlite3
from datetime import date

timedbname = '_' + str(date.today()).replace('-','_')

# Connecting to the database file
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE %s (col1 int, col2 int)''' % (timedbname))
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO %s VALUES (1, 2)''' % (timedbname))
cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM %s'''%timedbname).fetchall()
```